# Select from either a list or select all the values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, sql-in

SQL Server question -
I am trying to fetch some records from lets say a table named BUDGET. The filter used is Cost Center (CostC).
I have created the query such that if there are mutiple CostC, then it will be

```
select costc,description,budget from BUDGET where costc IN ('c1',c2',c3')
```

But I also need a feature so that, in case there is no list, then the filter on COSTC should look for all (*) cost centres.

Answer (score 0):

One option uses `union all` and `not exists`:

```
select costc, description, budget 
from budget 
where costc in ('c1', 'c2', 'c3')
union all
select costc, description, budget 
from budget
where not exists (select 1 from budget where costsc in ('c1', 'c2', 'c3'))
```

You can also use window functions:

```
select costc, description, budget 
from (
    select 
        b.*, 
        max(case when costc in ('c1', 'c2', 'c3') then 1 else 0 end) over() has_match
    from budget b
) b
where costc in ('c1', 'c2', 'c3') or has_match = 0
```

Comment: Thank you GMB. The issue is, my select query itself many many joins and UNION in it. If I Try to add another UNION or a Subquery, then the running cost of the whole query will increase. Is there a way so that I can externally define the behavior of the filter such that, either its a LIST or it selects all. I am aware that for List we use 'IN' and for all we will use 'LIKE'

Comment: @SugandhaSharma: no, I don't think there is a simpler method (otherwise I would have suggested it in the first place).

Comment: right. But thanks. Even this suggestion is useful, and I can certainly apply it somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

you can rewrite the union from @GMB s answer:

```
select costc, description, budget 
from budget 
where costc in ('c1', 'c2', 'c3')
or not exists (select 1 from budget where costc in ('c1', 'c2', 'c3'))
```

the resulting execution plan will probably the same as the one from the union.

or if its cheap to generate a list of all costc:

```
select something
from manymanyjoinsquery 
where costc in 
(  select costc 
        from budget 
        where costc in ('c1', 'c2', 'c3')
        or not exists (select 1 from budget where costsc in ('c1', 'c2', 'c3'))
)
```